# Using Attribute Proximity in Blender 3.0

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I have followed a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mjitYBn3s0) to create a node that changes material based on the proximity of an ellipse but quickly realized that some nodes have been replaced in blender 3.0 and I'm not sure how to get the same effect using the updated nodes like "Geometry Proximity". Hopefully, someone can help me out.

Geometry nodes and material Attribute:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There have been significant changes between 3.0 GN and earlier versions.  It appears that you're using nodes that were created in an earlier version.  While 3.0 will try to import these, most of them are so different that they won't actually do anything.  What you want is something like this:

[image]

What I'm really doing is creating a field-- a function-- that gets run on geometry and outputs to attribute "D".  That field takes the position of the geometry, at the time that it is evaluated (which is currently during the Group Output, but in the future should be *just before* the Group Output) and uses it to judge proximity to the target object's faces.

I'm showing a lot of things in this image, and a lot of them are important.  On the sidebar of the geometry nodes editor, I've defined what type of data the "Value" output has, in this case, a single Float.  In the modifier, I've specified which attribute to use to hold the output of the geometry nodes.  These are not optional.

Comment: Thank you that works!

Comment: huh. i better start learning the nodes now or I'll fall too far behind :)